# Getting magento Attribute on item returns blank

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to get some custom attributes to show in magento like Color, Delivery_Time...

I could call Some Attributes with :

```
<?php echo $item->getName();?>
<?php echo $item->getWeight();?>
```

But i could'nt call the most of the attributes. i've tried also :

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($item->getData('luftkammern'));?>
<?php echo $item->getAttributeText('spannung'); ?>
```

Nothing works!!

---

Code of attributes :

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <col width="25%" />
    <col />
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product,$_data['value'],    $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

---

2. code

   echo $this->__('Additional Information');?>

   ```
       <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
           <col width="25%" />
           <col />
           <tbody>
           <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
               <tr>
                   <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                   <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
               </tr>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   ```

---

can anyone help please ?

Comment: Are you gonna get those attributes in product page?

Comment: no i want to get the Attributes in the checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get those attributes in checkout page, you can do like this :

```
$_product = $item->getProduct();
$pid = $_product->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
/* getting some attributes */
$color = $product->getData('color');
$manufacturer = $product->getData('manufacturer');
$delivery_date = $product->getData('delivery_date');
....
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. i've tried it now with the color. But i just get an integer number instead of the right string of the color! (for green : 5, for white/black : 28 ....)

Comment: <?php echo $product->getAttributeText('color'); ?>

Comment: Thank you very much. it works!! 
i have one more question: is there a way to call the "Table of attributes" in the checkout page ? for example from this page : http://bengar.de/de/schlauchboot-angelboot-gruen-240-cm.html directly in the checkout page ? that would be awesome!

Comment: Well, please let me know how you showed that Table of attributes in product page. If you showed by using attribute like "$product->getData('table_description')", it is possible.

Comment: posted the second answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get attributes from a product by calling the correct get function.

For example to receive the **color** use:

```
echo $item->getColor();
```

To receive the **manufacturer** use:

```
echo $item->getManufacturer();
```

Also you have to make sure that your product has been fully loaded. Try this:

```
print_r($item->getData());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i've tried those get functions but without any results. 
print_r.. gave me a script error (i've surrounded it with '<pre>'!)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code:

```
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    $additional_data = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined()) {
            $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

            if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
            } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');
            } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
            }

            if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                $additional_data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                    'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                    'value' => $value,
                    'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                );
            }
        }
    }

    /* Your code here */
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    ...
    <?php foreach ($additional_data as $_data): ?>
    ...
```

Comment: hmmm i am afraid it didn't work for me! 
i've added this to the end : updated my post!

Comment: All i can get is the string of : "Additional information"